Drawing a simple mediation diagram with coefficients in R
Please could someone advise how to draw a mediation diagram similar to the one attached? I have tried the Diagrammar + Graphviz but can’t get the values under stress (1.00), wellbeing (0.62) and above self-esteem (0.80) to show on the plot. Does anyone know of an R package that can recreate the mediation diagram like the one attached?

depending on how you have estimated your model, perhaps https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/semPlot/index.html

Using the ggraph package might give a visually attractive result, and the colors, text, font, arrows etc are fully customizable too.
library(tidygraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggraph)

nodes <- c("Self-esteem\n0.80", "a\n-0.42", "Stress\n1.00",
           "c\n-0.32", "Wellbeing\n0.62", "b\n0.28")

data.frame(from = nodes, to = c(nodes[-1], nodes[1])) |>
  as_tbl_graph() |>
  mutate(x = c(0, -0.5, -1, 0, 1, 0.5), 
         y = 2 * sin(pi/3) * c(1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5)) |>
  ggraph(layout = "manual", x = x, y = y) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(end_cap = circle(rep(c(0, 1.5), 3))),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, "mm"), type = "closed")) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = rep(2:1/10, 3),
                       fill = factor(rep(2:1/10, 3)))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray85", "white"), guide = "none") +
  theme_graph() +
  coord_equal()



Thank you @Allan. Please how do I increase the size of the circle, as when I ran the code the text did not fit into the circle?

@Baz change geom_node_circle(aes(r = rep(2:1/10, 3), to geom_node_circle(aes(r = rep(c(0.5, 0.25), 3),. The 0.5 and 0.25 are the new sizes of the large and small circles. Change these to whatever you like

Or just drag your plotting window to make the plot larger. The circles will get bigger but the text won't.

thank you so much. That works. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to draw a rectangle or square shape instead of a circle? Just similar to the one I attached. Thank you

I think geom_node_label would draw the nodes as rectangles rather than circles @Baz.
